# php command that run sql DELETE query but not executing in DB

Tags: php, mysql, html

i wrote this MYsql DELETE function in php

```
function DeleteProduct($thisCatalog) {

    $connB = new ProductDAO();
    $connB->Connect();
    $pro_query = "DELETE * FROM Ikea WHERE `CatalogNumber` = $thisCatalog";
    $db_result = $connB->ExecSQL($pro_query);

    $html_result = 'Your Product Has Been Deleted! ';

    $connB->Disconnect();
    return $html_result;
}
```

this is the executing commend

```
DeleteProduct($CatalogNumber);
```

Comment: nothing happen in the db

Comment: make sure you quote and escape `$thisCatalog`

Comment: Check your sql logs, or catch your `ProductDAO` class errors - but please dare to put a least a question mark in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The delete syntax is different to the select syntax (You don't pick column names or use a `*` in it at all):

```
"DELETE FROM Ikea WHERE `CatalogNumber` = $thisCatalog";
```

Should do the trick.

And some examples from my test db:

```
mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | gggg  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into first values (7, 'cccc');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | gggg  |
|    7 | cccc  |
+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from first where id=7;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | gggg  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i change the syntax but it still does not delete from DB i think it is because we don't confirm the process , if i run in mysql db the command DELETE FROM `Ikea` WHERE `CatalogNumber`=78 i get a popup ask me to confirm . do you hava any idea?

Comment: @user1644661 When you say *mysql db* do you mean PHPMyAdmin? The Mysql Console doesn't have pop-ups?

Comment: @user1644661 All good, just trying to get the right understanding of what is going on. If the query works in PHPMyAdmin, then it should work perfectly well within a mysql query being sent to the database. Things that come to mind are: Are you running PHPMyAdmin under a different username/login to the connection you are making in your PHP - it might be a permissions thing for different users. Secondly, I am not all that familiar with DAO. Is this code you wrote yourself, or did you get it from somewhere?

Comment: i Appreciate your Intention my DAO and my primession are OK i wrote them myself and all the other things i Insert and read from the DB work very good ....this is Very strange :(

Comment: @user1644661 Here to learn and help others at the same time mate :)

Comment: @user1644661 It's hard to work it out. If the commmand works in PHPMyAdmin, it should work just as well in a Query. You aren't using transactions at all are you?

Comment: thank you for your help it finally working!i have forgeten the include my DAO :)))